# Function to calculate geospatial distance between two points (lat,long) using R

Tags: r, package, geospatial, distance, latitude-longitude

I have geocoded points in long, lat format, and I want to calculate the distance between them using R.  This seems pretty straight forward, yet I can't find a function that will do it easily.  I've been attempting to do it with the gdistance package, but it seems very convoluted and oriented to graphing, I just need a number.  Something like `distanceBetween(pointA,pointB)` that returns a number.

Comment: See `spDistsN1()` function in `sp` package.

Comment: Thanks Pascal that worked!

Comment: Did you see the answer from Jaap at http://stackoverflow.com/a/23095329/2514568?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Loading the geosphere package you can use a number of different functions

```
library(geosphere)
distm(c(lon1, lat1), c(lon2, lat2), fun = distHaversine)
```

Also:

```
distHaversine()
distMeeus()
distRhumb()
distVincentyEllipsoid()
distVincentySphere()
```

...

Comment: These all look useful as well!  Reading their descriptions they use just slightly different calculations.  I couldn't find the forest through the trees!

Comment: A small note. The method geosphere:distm is not vectorized. To vectorize it use the *apply* functions.

Comment: @DotPi It says in the documentation (version `1.5-5`) for `distm` that the first two arguments can be `Nx2` matrices (ie. collections of points), so I don't see the need for `apply` here?

Comment: @oens Thats for getting a matrix of distances from combining different points not just a Nx1 list of distances between the points

Comment: The distances returned by `distm` are meters by default. The documentation for `distm` does not mention the unit in which distances are returned by default, but this is mentioned in `distHaversine` documentation.

Comment: @DotPi do you have an example of how you would vectorize with apply? else it's runs veryyyyyy slow.

Comment: @ElChapo: There is not enough space in comments to add an example with code sample. I think it is fair to post your query as a new question if you can include sample data and your current attempt.

Comment: here's the vectorized version:
```dist_geo <- function(lat_a, lon_a, lat_b, lon_b) 
{
  if(anyNA(c(lat_a, lon_a, lat_b, lon_b))) return(NA)
  
  round(distm(c(lon_a, lat_a), c(lon_b, lat_b), fun = distHaversine)/1000,2)
}
dgeo$distance_km=mapply(lat_a=dgeo$latitude,
                    lon_a=dgeo$longitude, 
                    lat_b=dgeo$latitude_lag,
                    lon_b=dgeo$longitude_lag, 
                    FUN = dist_geo)```

Comment: you don't need to vectorize. distm(cbind(lon1,lat1),cbind(lon2,lat2)) returns the matrix of distances between all pairs of points, distHaversine(cbind(lon1,lat1),cbind(lon2,lat2)) returns the vector of distances between pairs of points.

Answer (score 24):

Agree with @PereG on answer above, but think that the order of latitude and longitude is the other way around: lon, lat. This will affect your results for distance matrix. So correct is:

```
library(geosphere)
distm (c(lon1, lat1), c(lon2, lat2), fun = distHaversine)
```

Source: ftp://cran.r-project.org/pub/R/web/packages/geosphere/geosphere.pdf

Comment: What is the unit of the output? Meters or Km or something else. 
If something else, how could I convert it to Meters?

Comment: Yes, as it says in manual, default is meters.