# R calculating distance between 2 points on earth using package geosphere

Tags: r, distance, geosphere

My question is based upon this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32363998/function-to-calculate-geospatial-distance-between-two-points-lat-long-using-r). Using it I wrote below code where first set of coordinates are for LGA airport NY while second set of coordinates are for EWR airport NY. I get the answer 33713. Is that in miles or in kilometers? A quick google check says that the distance should be 33 miles (but it is not a straigh line/arc distance :( It is a distance by road). The package [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/geosphere/geosphere.pdf) says that the answers are in meters. Please clarify. Is this a good method to find the distance on Earth given 2 coordinates? How can I get answer in Miles?

```
library(geosphere)
distm (c(40.777250, -73.872610), c(40.6895, -74.1745), fun = distHaversine)
         [,1]
[1,] 33713.61
```

Comment: Voting to close, there is no question here, only interpretation. The documentation is clear, and the conversion from meters to miles is trivial.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, it's giving you the answer in meters. To convert to miles:

```
> distm(c(40.777250, -73.872610), c(40.6895, -74.1745), fun = distHaversine)[,1] / 1609
[1] 20.95315
```

20.95 miles as the crow flies.