# subset first and last date and calculate euclidean distance

Tags: r, date, coordinates, subset, euclidean-distance

I have a dataset with a column of dates `Datum`. These dates have coordinates in `Longitude` and `Latitude` and belong to an unique ID called `HEX_Tag_ID`. I want to calculate the distance in meters between the earliest dates of every ID and the latest occuring dates of these ID's. I already got some code that really helped me calculating the distance between every given date of an ID, but now I only want the distance between the earliest (start) and latest (end) date.

Code I used:

```
Afstand_m <- df_detecties_compleet %>% 
  group_by(HEX_Tag_ID) %>% 
  arrange(Datum) %>%  # Sort the dataframe by Date                                     
  mutate(
    Afstand = sqrt((x - lag(x))^2 + (y - lag(y))^2),  # The "lag" function shifts a vector 
    date_start = lag(Datum),
    date_end = Datum) %>%
  drop_na(Afstand) %>% # Removes rows with distance == NA, because the lag function return an NA for the first element 
  select(HEX_Tag_ID, date_start, date_end, Afstand, `Lengte_(cm)`, Geslacht, Sloot, Lengteklasse)
```

df = df_detecties_compleet

```
structure(list(Datum_Tijd = structure(c(1653901791, 1655101326, 
1653893478, 1654845521, 1654238048, 1653632032, 1653302358, 1653631928, 
1655103098, 1653893460, 1653027080, 1654238053, 1654838433, 1654579930, 
1655109536, 1653891610, 1653301384, 1653023256, 1653301069, 1654585048, 
1654845726, 1654235912, 1653638389, 1653900204, 1653286087, 1654579725, 
1655071201, 1653900967, 1653287064, 1653639241, 1654839303, 1655111038, 
1653023103, 1653301359, 1653022257, 1654844287, 1654585645, 1653023789, 
1654236992, 1654237269, 1653025947, 1653631090, 1653629670, 1653301006, 
1654584948, 1655100212, 1653023792, 1654235809, 1654585387, 1653900459, 
1654838820, 1654243915, 1653286385, 1654594795, 1653300279, 1653890934, 
1653629089, 1655118390, 1653032025, 1654235007, 1654584868, 1655100030, 
1654586799, 1654237883, 1654599824, 1653290733, 1655114189, 1653904978, 
1654843618, 1654236016, 1654585307, 1653891825, 1653629934, 1654236207, 
1653301534, 1655100739, 1653900023, 1655109075, 1653030923, 1654838117, 
1653286092, 1654243157, 1654237467, 1653302633, 1654586302, 1653026216, 
1653631495, 1654580433, 1653031865, 1653286665, 1653638972, 1654244428, 
1653900853, 1654838661, 1654580154, 1655110042, 1655118041, 1654600083, 
1653910340, 1653628861), tzone = "", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
)), Datum = structure(c(19142, 19156, 19142, 19153, 19146, 19139, 
19135, 19139, 19156, 19142, 19132, 19146, 19153, 19150, 19156, 
19142, 19135, 19132, 19135, 19150, 19153, 19146, 19139, 19142, 
19135, 19150, 19156, 19142, 19135, 19139, 19153, 19156, 19132, 
19135, 19132, 19153, 19150, 19132, 19146, 19146, 19132, 19139, 
19139, 19135, 19150, 19156, 19132, 19146, 19150, 19142, 19153, 
19146, 19135, 19150, 19135, 19142, 19139, 19156, 19132, 19146, 
19150, 19156, 19150, 19146, 19150, 19135, 19156, 19142, 19153, 
19146, 19150, 19142, 19139, 19146, 19135, 19156, 19142, 19156, 
19132, 19153, 19135, 19146, 19146, 19135, 19150, 19132, 19139, 
19150, 19132, 19135, 19139, 19146, 19142, 19153, 19150, 19156, 
19156, 19150, 19142, 19139), class = "Date"), Tijd = c("11:09:51", 
"08:22:06", "08:51:18", "09:18:41", "08:34:08", "08:13:52", "12:39:18", 
"08:12:08", "08:51:38", "08:51:00", "08:11:20", "08:34:13", "07:20:33", 
"07:32:10", "10:38:56", "08:20:10", "12:23:04", "07:07:36", "12:17:49", 
"08:57:28", "09:22:06", "07:58:32", "09:59:49", "10:43:24", "08:08:07", 
"07:28:45", "00:00:01", "10:56:07", "08:24:24", "10:14:01", "07:35:03", 
"11:03:58", "07:05:03", "12:22:39", "06:50:57", "08:58:07", "09:07:25", 
"07:16:29", "08:16:32", "08:21:09", "07:52:27", "07:58:10", "07:34:30", 
"12:16:46", "08:55:48", "08:03:32", "07:16:32", "07:56:49", "09:03:07", 
"10:47:39", "07:27:00", "10:11:55", "08:13:05", "11:39:55", "12:04:39", 
"08:08:54", "07:24:49", "13:06:30", "09:33:45", "07:43:27", "08:54:28", 
"08:00:30", "09:26:39", "08:31:23", "13:03:44", "09:25:33", "11:56:29", 
"12:02:58", "08:46:58", "08:00:16", "09:01:47", "08:23:45", "07:38:54", 
"08:03:27", "12:25:34", "08:12:19", "10:40:23", "10:31:15", "09:15:23", 
"07:15:17", "08:08:12", "09:59:17", "08:24:27", "12:43:53", "09:18:22", 
"07:56:56", "08:04:55", "07:40:33", "09:31:05", "08:17:45", "10:09:32", 
"10:20:28", "10:54:13", "07:24:21", "07:35:54", "10:47:22", "13:00:41", 
"13:08:03", "13:32:20", "07:21:01"), Reader_ID = c("A0", "A0", 
"A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", 
"A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", 
"A0", "A0", "Lite", "A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", 
"A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", 
"A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", 
"A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", 
"A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", 
"A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", 
"A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", "A0"
), HEX_Tag_ID = c("3D6.15343A9C1C", "3D6.15343A9E7E", "3D6.15343A9E9D", 
"3D6.15343A9E9D", "3D6.15343A9E9D", "3D6.15343A9E9D", "3D6.15343A9EF5", 
"3D6.15343A9F0C", "3D6.15343A9F0C", "3D6.15343A9F0C", "3D6.15343A9F0C", 
"3D6.15343A9F0C", "3D6.15343A9F13", "3D6.15343A9F13", "3D6.15343A9F13", 
"3D6.15343A9F18", "3D6.15343A9F18", "3D6.15343A9F18", "3D6.15343AA124", 
"3D6.15343AA124", "3D6.15343AA124", "3D6.15343AA124", "3D6.15343AA28F", 
"3D6.15343AA28F", "3D6.15343AA28F", "3D6.15343AA28F", "3D6.15343AA28F", 
"3D6.15343AA34A", "3D6.15343AA34A", "3D6.15343AA34A", "3D6.15343AA3B4", 
"3D6.15343AA3B4", "3D6.15343AA3C9", "3D6.15343AA3C9", "3D6.15343AA3CD", 
"3D6.15343AA503", "3D6.15343AA503", "3D6.15343AA512", "3D6.15343AA5EC", 
"3D6.15343AA601", "3D6.15343AA601", "3D6.15343AA601", "3D6.15343AA680", 
"3D6.15343AA680", "3D6.15343AA680", "3D6.15343AA680", "3D6.15343AA680", 
"3D6.15343AA680", "3D6.15343AA694", "3D6.15343AA6BB", "3D6.15343AA6BB", 
"3D6.15343AA6BB", "3D6.15343AA6BB", "3D6.15343AA6CD", "3D6.15343AA6CD", 
"3D6.15343AA6CD", "3D6.15343AA6CD", "3D6.15343AA6CD", "3D6.15343AA6D0", 
"3D6.15343AA722", "3D6.15343AA72F", "3D6.15343AA72F", "3D6.15343AA768", 
"3D6.15343AA768", "3D6.15343AA8D5", "3D6.15343AA8D5", "3D6.15343AA8D5", 
"3D6.15343AA8D5", "3D6.15343AA8E6", "3D6.15343AA8E6", "3D6.15343AA9A2", 
"3D6.15343AA9A2", "3D6.15343AA9A2", "3D6.15343AA9A2", "3D6.15343AA9A2", 
"3D6.15343AA9A2", "3D6.15343AA9F9", "3D6.15343AA9F9", "3D6.15343AA9F9", 
"3D6.15343AA9F9", "3D6.15343AA9F9", "3D6.15343AA9F9", "3D6.15343AAA05", 
"3D6.15343AAA05", "3D6.15343AAA05", "3D6.15343AAA05", "3D6.15343AAA16", 
"3D6.15343AAB0D", "3D6.15343AAB0D", "3D6.15343AAB0D", "3D6.15343AAB0D", 
"3D6.15343AAB0D", "3D6.15343AAB0D", "3D6.15343AB519", "3D6.15343AB519", 
"3D6.15343AB519", "3D6.15343AD0ED", "3D6.15343AD0ED", "3D6.15343AD0ED", 
"3D6.15343AD0ED"), Longitude = c(4.70894, 4.71152, 4.71123, 4.71127, 
4.71125, 4.71122, 4.71137, 4.71124, 4.71118, 4.71123, 4.71124, 
4.71125, 4.70905, 4.70908, 4.70908, 4.71148, 4.71148, 4.7115, 
4.71149, 4.71146, 4.71124, 4.71148, 4.7091, 4.70913, 4.70911, 
4.70909, NA, 4.70903, 4.70902, 4.70905, 4.70898, 4.70897, 4.71151, 
4.71148, 4.71161, 4.7114, 4.71139, 4.71146, 4.71136, 4.71134, 
4.71133, 4.71134, 4.71146, 4.71149, 4.71146, 4.71146, 4.71146, 
4.71148, 4.71142, 4.70911, 4.70902, 4.70909, 4.70909, 4.71104, 
4.71158, 4.7116, 4.71152, 4.71152, 4.70902, 4.71158, 4.71147, 
4.71146, 4.71129, 4.71126, 4.71035, 4.71023, 4.71042, 4.71021, 
4.71149, 4.71145, 4.71142, 4.71144, 4.71143, 4.71144, 4.71146, 
4.71137, 4.70916, 4.70912, 4.70907, 4.70908, 4.70911, 4.70907, 
4.71132, 4.71133, 4.71131, 4.71131, 4.71128, 4.70902, 4.70903, 
4.70906, 4.70907, 4.70902, 4.70904, 4.70904, 4.70906, 4.70904, 
4.71129, 4.71127, 4.71161, 4.71157), Latitude = c(51.931381, 
51.932899, 51.931122, 51.931091, 51.931122, 51.930939, 51.932369, 
51.931099, 51.931099, 51.931122, 51.93111, 51.931122, 51.93301, 
51.93298, 51.932991, 51.933868, 51.933899, 51.934292, 51.93404, 
51.934021, 51.930752, 51.934021, 51.933231, 51.933262, 51.933369, 
51.933239, NA, 51.932362, 51.932339, 51.932331, 51.931839, 51.93187, 
51.93441, 51.933899, 51.935211, 51.932999, 51.933029, 51.93399, 
51.932449, 51.932171, 51.932041, 51.932171, 51.93401, 51.93404, 
51.934181, 51.934139, 51.93399, 51.934158, 51.93343, 51.933029, 
51.932499, 51.932968, 51.932999, 51.93544, 51.935242, 51.934978, 
51.93494, 51.935551, 51.93248, 51.935268, 51.934349, 51.93428, 
51.931271, 51.931301, 51.935242, 51.93539, 51.93536, 51.935379, 
51.93399, 51.933868, 51.933578, 51.933609, 51.93362, 51.933609, 
51.93362, 51.93364, 51.93351, 51.933491, 51.93335, 51.933479, 
51.933369, 51.933552, 51.932018, 51.93195, 51.931889, 51.9319, 
51.931549, 51.932331, 51.93261, 51.932739, 51.93261, 51.932461, 
51.932499, 51.932758, 51.93272, 51.93277, 51.93552, 51.93536, 
51.935429, 51.9352), x = c(108351.54, 108530.55, 108508.767, 
108511.486, 108510.142, 108507.89, 108519.685, 108509.431, 108505.304, 
108508.767, 108509.442, 108510.142, 108360.796, 108362.828, 108362.84, 
108528.801, 108528.833, 108530.615, 108529.667, 108527.584, 108509.072, 
108528.959, 108364.464, 108366.56, 108365.295, 108363.785, NA, 
108358.748, 108358.037, 108360.091, 108354.767, 108354.111, 108531.425, 
108528.833, 108539.13, 108522.4, 108521.744, 108527.552, 108519.081, 
108517.417, 108516.595, 108517.417, 108527.573, 108529.667, 108527.749, 
108527.706, 108527.552, 108529.101, 108524.222, 108364.942, 108358.203, 
108363.504, 108363.536, 108500.169, 108537.099, 108538.202, 108532.661, 
108533.293, 108358.183, 108537.126, 108528.611, 108527.852, 108513.048, 
108511.015, 108452.513, 108444.414, 108457.449, 108443.027, 108529.615, 
108526.738, 108524.375, 108525.782, 108525.106, 108525.782, 108527.169, 
108521, 108368.88, 108366.11, 108362.525, 108363.346, 108365.295, 
108362.734, 108515.884, 108516.501, 108515.062, 108515.074, 108512.647, 
108358.028, 108359.006, 108361.203, 108361.757, 108358.163, 108359.578, 
108359.847, 108361.183, 108359.859, 108517.444, 108515.903, 108539.356, 
108536.368), y = c(438318.956, 438486.186, 438288.674, 438285.2, 
438288.662, 438268.322, 438427.318, 438286.109, 438286.148, 438288.674, 
438287.333, 438288.662, 438500.117, 438496.76, 438497.984, 438594.016, 
438597.465, 438641.174, 438613.145, 438611.05, 438247.504, 438611.038, 
438524.672, 438528.102, 438540.019, 438525.568, NA, 438428.038, 
438425.486, 438424.576, 438369.885, 438373.34, 438654.296, 438597.465, 
438743.346, 438497.388, 438500.732, 438607.602, 438436.224, 438405.309, 
438390.852, 438405.309, 438609.827, 438613.145, 438628.851, 438624.178, 
438607.602, 438626.279, 438545.325, 438502.192, 438443.286, 438495.419, 
438498.868, 438769.187, 438746.814, 438717.43, 438713.254, 438781.23, 
438441.172, 438749.707, 438647.535, 438639.865, 438305.213, 438308.57, 
438747.601, 438764.143, 438760.684, 438762.932, 438607.582, 438594.035, 
438561.791, 438565.227, 438566.457, 438565.227, 438566.438, 438568.72, 
438555.673, 438553.585, 438537.93, 438552.276, 438540.019, 438560.404, 
438388.3, 438380.728, 438373.954, 438375.178, 438336.148, 438424.595, 
438455.629, 438469.961, 438455.603, 438439.058, 438443.273, 438472.088, 
438467.847, 438473.423, 438777.928, 438760.14, 438767.599, 438742.148
), `Lengte_(cm)` = c(10.9, 8.8, 8.6, 8.6, 8.6, 8.6, 8, 9.3, 9.3, 
9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 9.9, 9.9, 9.9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9.5, 
9.5, 9.5, 9.5, 9.5, 12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 7.7, 7.7, 10.8, 10.8, 11, 
7.5, 7.5, 7.4, 8.2, 9.9, 9.9, 9.9, 11.2, 11.2, 11.2, 11.2, 11.2, 
11.2, 11.5, 10, 10, 10, 10, 9.4, 9.4, 9.4, 9.4, 9.4, 10.8, 10, 
9.7, 9.7, 9.8, 9.8, 11.2, 11.2, 11.2, 11.2, 7.2, 7.2, 11, 11, 
11, 11, 11, 11, 11.8, 11.8, 11.8, 11.8, 11.8, 11.8, 8.6, 8.6, 
8.6, 8.6, 9.4, 9.7, 9.7, 9.7, 9.7, 9.7, 9.7, 10.7, 10.7, 10.7, 
9, 9, 9, 9), Geslacht = c("vrouw", "vrouw", "man", "man", "man", 
"man", "vrouw", "vrouw", "vrouw", "vrouw", "vrouw", "vrouw", 
"vrouw", "vrouw", "vrouw", "vrouw", "vrouw", "vrouw", "vrouw", 
"vrouw", "vrouw", "vrouw", "vrouw", "vrouw", "vrouw", "vrouw", 
"vrouw", "vrouw", "vrouw", "vrouw", "vrouw", "vrouw", "man", 
"man", "vrouw", "man", "man", "man", "man", "vrouw", "vrouw", 
"vrouw", "vrouw", "vrouw", "vrouw", "vrouw", "vrouw", "vrouw", 
"man", "vrouw", "vrouw", "vrouw", "vrouw", "vrouw", "vrouw", 
"vrouw", "vrouw", "vrouw", "man", "man", "vrouw", "vrouw", "man", 
"man", "vrouw", "vrouw", "vrouw", "vrouw", "vrouw", "vrouw", 
"vrouw", "vrouw", "vrouw", "vrouw", "vrouw", "vrouw", "man", 
"man", "man", "man", "man", "man", "vrouw", "vrouw", "vrouw", 
"vrouw", "vrouw", "vrouw", "vrouw", "vrouw", "vrouw", "vrouw", 
"vrouw", "vrouw", "vrouw", "vrouw", "man", "man", "man", "man"
), Sloot = c("22", "26", "26", "26", "26", "26", "26", "26", 
"26", "26", "26", "26", "22", "22", "22", "26", "26", "26", "26", 
"26", "26", "26", "22", "22", "22", "22", "Zuid 18-24", "22", 
"22", "22", "22", "22", "26", "26", "26", "26", "26", "26", "26", 
"26", "26", "26", "26", "26", "26", "26", "26", "26", "26", "22", 
"22", "22", "22", "Noord", "26", "26", "26", "Noord", "22", "26", 
"26", "26", "26", "26", "Noord", "Noord", "Noord", "Noord", "26", 
"26", "26", "26", "26", "26", "26", "26", "22", "22", "22", "22", 
"22", "22", "26", "26", "26", "26", "26", "22", "22", "22", "22", 
"22", "22", "22", "22", "22", "Noord", "Noord", "Noord", "26"
), Lengte_8e_lichting = c(NA, 10.5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 10.1, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 10.5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 9.8, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 11.7, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 10.2, NA, NA, NA, 11, NA, NA, NA, NA, 11.6, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 11.3, NA, 11.4, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 12.3, 9.2, NA, NA, 
NA), Lengteklasse = structure(c(5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("6", 
"7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-100L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: You should consider using geographic distance: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32364246/1199289

Comment: Also considered this one :). Only not sure how to incorperate it for my question. How can I use this to calculate it between the first and last date of every ID? (still learning the ropes within r)

Answer (score 0):

This computes distances on the WGS84 ellipsoid.

```r
library(geosphere)
geo.dist <- sapply(split(df_detecties_compleet, 
                         df_detecties_compleet$HEX_Tag_ID), function(x) {
  x <- x[order(x$Datum), ]
  distm(x[c(1, nrow(x)), c('Longitude', 'Latitude')])[2]
})
```

`distm` returns a symmetric matrix of distances, hence the `[2]` to extract (one of) the off-diagonal elements. The result is a named vector of distances with IDs as names.

Comment: I wanted to give it a try but I received the following error: Error in unique.default(x, nmax = nmax) : 
  unique() applies only to vectors

Comment: That's strange, did you use it on the data you included in your question?

Comment: yes, the exact same data.

Comment: Ok, it is a bit more verbose now, but it should work for you. There was a problem with the specification of grouping factor in `split` which can be a formula in newer versions of R (I use 4.1.1) but not in older versions.

Comment: hmmm I am using version 4.0.2. Now it gives me the following error:  Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Comment: Hm.. that's even weirder. Please double check that you copied the code correctly.

Comment: it is strange indeed, I copied it correctly and used the same data as in my example. I have no clue why it doesn't work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246231/discussion-between-robert-hacken-and-pepijn95).